# Popover in material-ui - display glitches when using components

Tags: reactjs, popover, material-ui

It's a trivial issue but I'm not seeing where the problem exactly lies.

As far as I know, React offers the ability to pull stuff apart into (somewhat) independent components which results in cleaner pages because not everything is crammed into one huge HTML file. Or so the philosophy goes, I think.

Basically, when I do this, everything works fine:

```
<Popover open={this.props.popover === LoginPopoverState.LOGIN}
         anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
         onRequestClose={this.handleHideLogin.bind(this, dispatch)}>
     <div style={loginStyle}>
          <TextField hintText="Username oder E-Mail" ref="username_login" floatingLabelText="Username / E-Mail"/><br />
          <TextField hintText="Passwort" type="password" ref="password_login" floatingLabelText="Passwort" /><br />
          <RaisedButton label="Login" onTouchTap={e => this.handleLoginTap(e, dispatch)} />
          <p>Zur <a href="javascript://" onTouchTap={e => this.handleShowRegisterTap(e, dispatch)}>Registration</a>.</p>
     </div>
</Popover>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Nicely styled]

However, when I pull out the `<div>` into another module and then do something like this:

```
import LoginFragment from './loginBar/LoginFragment.jsx'
<Popover open={this.props.popover === LoginPopoverState.LOGIN}
         anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
         onRequestClose={this.handleHideLogin.bind(this, dispatch)}>
     <LoginFragment />
</Popover>
```

where LoginFragment.jsx contains something like this:

```
var LoginFragment = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <TextField hintText="Username oder E-Mail" ref="username_login" floatingLabelText="Username / E-Mail"/>
        )
    }
})
```

Which results in this hot mess:

[image: Not nicely styled]

So, what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a CSS styling issue, since you aren´t wrapping your fields inside a div anymore (and you are now skipping the loginStyle that was applied to this containing div.)

So, in the old version you had:

```
<Popover ...>
     <div style={loginStyle}>
          <TextField ...><br />
          <TextField ...><br />
          <RaisedButton .../>
          <p>...</p>
     </div>
</Popover>
```

But what you are including in your new version right now, using a single LoginFragment component, once expanded, would look like:

```
<Popover ...>         

          <TextField ...>

</Popover>
```

In this version, the wrapping divs (and their styling) would be missing. Including `<div style={loginStyle}>` in your code again would fix any CSS styling conflict, or help find and isolate the issue. Like so:

```
import LoginFragment from './loginBar/LoginFragment.jsx'
<Popover open={this.props.popover === LoginPopoverState.LOGIN}
         anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
         onRequestClose={this.handleHideLogin.bind(this, dispatch)}>
     <div style={loginStyle}>
         <LoginFragment />
     </div>
</Popover>
```

Comment: Already tried that. Wrapping it in a div doesn't change anything, sadly enough.

Comment: That should discard a CSS / styling issue, then. I guess nothing would change if you added a <br/> after <LoginFragment /> in your last version. Other than that, are you seeing any javascript errors in your javascript console?

Comment: No errors either. That's why I'm a bit stumped on how to debug this.